# SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin iOS Unable To Launch the Startpage

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, cordova

> cordova create
>
> cd
>
> npm init
>
> npm install shelljs@0.7.0 --save
>
> cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
>
> cordova plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin
>
> cordova platform add android@6.1.0
>
> cordova platform add ios@4.3.0

//copy a completed bootconfig.json file to www/

> cordova prepare

The  android working fine, it calls the start page but in iOS it's odd because after the successful login, it doesn't call the star page, what's shown is white screen.

Here's the log from XCode:

2017/03/24 05:38:11.383 hybrid[15195:1f07] DEBUG com.salesforce : popViewController: View controller ((null)) not found in the view controller stack.  No action taken.
2017/03/24 05:38:11.772 hybrid[15195:1b03] DEBUG com.salesforce : webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler: Loading URL '/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=[redacted]&retURL=https%3A%2F%2F%2Fidex.html&display=touch'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix:

1. In Xcode, open your hybrid remote project.
2. List item In the Project Navigator, expand the Plugins folder.
3. Select the AppDelegate+SalesforceHybridSDK.m file.
4. In the code editor, find the setupRootViewController method definition.
5. On theright-hand side of the self.viewController assignment, add a user UIWebView:YES argument to the end of the parameter list:

> self.viewController = [[SFHybridViewController alloc]
>       initWithConfig:(SFHybridViewConfig*)
>           [SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].appConfig 
>        useUIWebView:YES];

Please see this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/hybrid_develop_hybrid_remote.htm).